# Как узнать о том, что значение превысило диапазон?

Tags: c

Читаю Кернигана и Ритчи ( «The C programming language. SE.» ), там такое задание:

> «**Упражнение 2.1.** Напишите программу для определения диапазонов переменных типов char, short, int, и long ( как signed, так и unsigned ) путем вывода соответствующих значений из заголовочных файлов, а также с помощью непосредственного вычисления. Для второго способа усложним задачу: определите еще и диапазоны вещественных типов.»

Со значениями из  заголовочных файлов всё понятно, а вот как определить, что значение превысило диапазон?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Если целое число достигло своего максимального значения, то после инкремента оно станет равным нулю для беззнаковых чисел и отрицательным для знаковых. [Переполнение(вики)](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%84%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5). Более быстрый способ - сдвигать побитово единицу влево и определить количество бит в числе. Тогда максимальное значение равно (2^n)-1.

Comment: Спасибо, большое. Разобрался. ) Я просто сначала сделал так:

`char ch = 0; /* max 127 */ printf( "%i", ch + 300 );`   

Он выдавал 300. Как я понимаю, результат приводился к int'у. Ну, теперь понятно. Спасибо еще раз за ответ на такой нубский вопрос. ))

Comment: Переполнение  знаковых типов - неопределённое поведение. Плохой совет.